# Given n as input, print the following pattern -1+2-3+4-5+....(+/-)n = n, with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have tried many times but I can't find the values, how can I solve this? Here's my code:

```js
var number = prompt("");
for (var count = 1; count <= number; count++) {

  if (count % 2 != 0) {
    console.log("-");
    document.write("-");
    // console.log(count);
    document.write(count);
  } else {
    console.log("+");
    document.write("+");
    // console.log(count);
    document.write(count);
  }

}
document.write("=", );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```js
var number = prompt("");
var result = 0;
for (var count = 1; count <= number; count++) {

  if (count % 2 != 0) {
    document.write("-");
    document.write(count);
    result -= count;
  } else {
    document.write("+");
    document.write(count);
    result += count;
  }

}
document.write("=" + result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A declarive solution. (as a fan of declarative programming)

```js
const func = (n) => {
[...Array(n)].map( (_,i) => (
    i%2 === 0 ? console.log(`-${i+1}`) : console.log(`+${i+1}`)
))}

func(6)
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
var flag = true;
var result=0;
var str = "";
var n=10;
for(let i=1;i<n;i++){
if(flag){
   str += "-"; 
   result -= i;
}
else{
   str += "+";
   result += i;
}
str += i;
flag = !flag
}

str += "="+result;
console.log(str);
```

Comment: i want this output  as same print -1+2-3+4-5+6=3

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution (with [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eobh2kp4/)).

```js
function expandString(n) {
    let str = '';

  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 1) {
        str += `-${i}`; // Even
    } else {
      str += `+${i}`; // Odd
    }
  }

  return str += ` = ${n}`;
}

console.log(expandString(5));
```